# c language result is different in windows 10

Tags: c

The result looks like bug!
the code result is different in window 10 and ubuntu
as I expected result is:

if input 5;
expected result (it work in ubunt )

5
The number 5

is not divisible by 3.

5 (it work in windows 10 )
The number 5 - 35

is divisible by 3.

in Visual Studio(Cl.exe exited code 2)

I have no idea why is -35 attached in my result and wrong calculation!

in window 10 eclipse cygwin gcc

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct digit
{
    int num;
    struct digit *next;
};
struct digit *createDigit(int dig);
struct digit * append(struct digit * end, struct digit * newDigptr);
void printNumber(struct digit *start);
struct digit *readNumber(void);
void freeNumber(struct digit *start);
int divisibleByThree(struct digit *ptr);

int main(void) {

    struct digit *start;
    start = readNumber();

    printf("The number ");
    printNumber(start);
    if (divisibleByThree(start))
        printf("is divisible by 3.\n");
    else
        printf("is not divisible by 3.\n");
    freeNumber(start);
    return 0;
}

struct digit *createDigit(int dig) {
    struct digit *ptr;
    ptr = (struct digit *) malloc(sizeof(struct digit));
    ptr->num = dig;
    ptr->next = NULL;
    return ptr;
}

struct digit * append(struct digit * end, struct digit * newDigptr) {
    end->next = newDigptr;
    return(end->next);
}

void printNumber(struct digit *start) {
    struct digit * ptr = start;
    while (ptr!=NULL) {
        printf("%d", ptr->num);
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void freeNumber(struct digit *start) {
    struct digit * ptr = start;
    struct digit * tmp;
    while (ptr!=NULL) {
        tmp = ptr->next;
        free(ptr);
        ptr = tmp;
    }
}


struct digit *readNumber(void) {
    char c; // read character
    int d;
    struct digit *start, *end, *newptr;
    start = NULL;
    scanf("%c", &c);
    while (c != '\n') {
        d = c - 48; // character to integer
        newptr = createDigit(d);
        if (start == NULL) {
            start = newptr;
            end = start;
        } else {
            end = append(end, newptr); // linked to each other
        }
        scanf("%c", &c);
    }
    return(start);
}

int divisibleByThree(struct digit *start){
    struct digit *ptr = start;
    int i = ptr->num;
    int divisible = 3;
    while( ptr->next!= NULL){
        i = ptr->next->num + (i % divisible)*10;
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
    //printf("\n%d\n",i);
    if(i % divisible) return 0;
    else return 1;

}
```

5
The number 5
is not divisible by 3.
5
The number 5 - 35
is divisible by 3.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly learn how to create a [mcve].

Comment: All you've given is a the definition of a struct.  There's no code here that shows what you're trying to do.  Please update your question with a [mcve] that others can compile and run as is that replicates your problem.

Answer (score 4):

On windows you seem to read a `\r` which will give you -35 because `\r` has the value 13.

You need to make sure not to include non-digits in your list.

So change

```
while (c != '\n') {
```

to

```
while (isdigit(c)) {
```

or in case you want to check manually (instead of using `isdigit`)

```
while (c >= '0' && c <= '9') {
```

Note: `isdigit` require `#include <ctype.h>`

The different results on Linux and Windows is because they have different definitions for "newline". Linux just us "\n" while windows use "\r\n"

Comment: In which case, the input stream must have been opened in binary mode.

Comment: I got it I really appreciate it for you!